# From python, run python script in git-bash

Tags: python, windows, git-bash

From python, I need to run a python file inside of git bash, while running in Windows.

That is, I have a configuration script written in python that calls other python scripts. Unfortunately, some of them use Unix commands, so they must be run using git bash in Windows.

Currently I'm using this:

```py
cmd = f'{sys.executable} mydependency.py'
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# waiting for pipe is handled later...
```

However, this doesn't work, giving me a `cannot execute binary file` message. How can I get it to run?

PS: For slightly more context, `mydependency.py` is actually the `amalgamate.py` script from the simdjson (https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson) project.

EDIT:

I have also attempted the following:

- Switch to run or call instead of subprocess.Popen
- Use `f'{git_bash_path} {sys.executable} mydependency.py'`
- Change the shell and executable parameters of Popen,run and call

Comment: FWIW, `subprocess` doesn't work as intended on the windows environment always. I would use `subprocess.run` (or) `subprocess.call` within `git-bash`.

Comment: Note: git-bash has nothing to do with Git, it's just included with Git-for-Windows. It's just a port *of* bash to Windows. Git needs (or needed in the past, and still wants) a POSIX-compatible shell, so it comes with bash.

Comment: If you just start a `python.exe` process from your script, it's not going to just have a git-bash terminal attached. I don't think it has *any* terminal attached. If it does, it'd be the same one as the one running the current script - in which case, this setup can't solve a problem, because you're already in git-bash.

Comment: So I think what you need to do is use `subprocess` to open *a git-bash process*, and communicate the `python mydependency.py` command *to its standard input*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```py
cmd = git_bash_path # Found with glob.
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.communicate(input=f'{sys.executable} mydependency.py'.encode())
```

I'm not entirely sure why this works, if anyone has an explanation I'd be glad to hear it.